# cannot access wp-admin - nginx rev proxy from apache on lan

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm stuck.  I am running nginx as a reverse proxy server on a raspberry pi.  I have xampp as my apache server for my wordpress installs on win svr 2019.  I am self-hosting two sites.  They each have their own separate install folder in xampp/htdocs.  I cannot access wp-admin ("Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."), and I receive redirect errors when trying to load the site.  I've pieced together what I could from forums and guides from various sites. I'm new to this, any advice or better guides to make my configuration work, as well as any security concerns?

raspberry pi running nginx

```
192.168.1.10
```

my sites - xampp on win srv 2019 - separate wp installs

```
192.168.1.11:80/site1  
192.168.1.11:80/site2
```

/etc/nginx/ssl.conf  - all ssl settings

```
add_header                 Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
ssl_certificate            /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrcmrsn.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key        /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrcmrsn.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_dhparam                /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrcmrsn.com/dhparam.pem;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout        5m;
ssl_session_tickets        off;
ssl_stapling               on;
ssl_stapling_verify        on;
```

/etc/nginx/proxy-settings.conf - all proxy settings

```
proxy_hide_header       Origin;
proxy_hide_header       Referer;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

/etc/nginx/servers.conf - all listening servers - http via port 9090 - ssl via port 9443

```
server {
        listen 9090;
        listen [::]:9090;
        server_name *.mydomain.com;
               return 301               https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 9443 http2 ssl;
        listen [::]:9443 http2 ssl;
        include ssl.conf;
        server_name site1.mydomain.com www.site1.mydomain.com;
                location / {
                        include proxy-settings.conf;
                        proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.11:80/site1/;
                }
}
server {
        listen 9443 http2 ssl;
        listen [::]:9443 http2 ssl;
        include ssl.conf;
        server_name site2.mydomain.com www.site2.mydomain.com;
                location / {
                        include proxy-settings.conf;
                        proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.11:80/site2/;
                }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/xampp/htdocs/site1/wp-config.php - added the following lines

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
  $http_x_headers = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $http_x_headers[0];
}
define('WP_HOME','https://192.168.1.11:80/site1/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://192.168.1.11:80/site1/');
```